# How do I enable Server Side Includes for html file

Tags: html, apache

```
<!--#include virtual="filename.htm"-->
```

Currently, I don't see include file (html) content when I open page in browser.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html

Answer (score 1):

You use `virtual=` if the file you are calling for *is in a different directory* from the page which is calling for it.

Otherwise you use `file=`.

> **Rule of Thumb**
>
> Use `file=` when the included file is within the same directory as
>   the page that wants it.
>
> ```
> <!--#include file="included.html" -->
> ```
>
> Use `virtual=` when it isn't.
>
> ```
> <!--#include virtual="/directory/included.html" -->
> ```
>
> That forward slash before the first directory is representative of the
>   domain name (server root). By using that leading slash, the server
>   will add the domain name to the front of the address for you.
>
> **Source:** http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/article.php/3473341

---

### Additional Notes...

Perl-based Server Side Includes (SSI) of the format:

```
<!--#include virtual="/directory/included.html" -->
```

are not the only type of SSI you can deploy.

Alternatives include:

1) **ASP Includes** (for Windows-based servers):

```
<!-- #include virtual ="/directory/included.html" -->
```

2) **PHP Includes** (for Linux-based servers):

```
<?php include '[...SERVER_PATH...]/directory/included.html'; ?>
```

3) **HTML Imports** *(Becoming more widely available...)*

```
<link rel="import" href="/directory/included.html">
```

***N.B.*** HTML Imports work slightly differently to the other 3 types of include, given that they are only declared in the `<head>` of a page (not in the `<body>`) and once loaded, are intended to be manipulated within the DOM via Javascript...